# Finding Thevenin resistance for a bridge circuit with voltage source

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, thevenin

To find Thevenin resistance, I've shorted the voltage source and have attempted to find equivalent resistance. However, I'm stuck on why they decided to add R1 and R2 resistors in parallel. From my understanding, if the current can only flow through the two resistors, they are in series. Why did they add them in parallel?

[image: bridge amplifier circuit]

Comment: Vs is a short circuit when determining the Thevenin resistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you short the voltage source the ends of R1 and R2 that connect to *a* are connected, the other ends that were connected to the voltage source are also connected (because you shorted the source), that means that R1 and R2 are connected together at both ends which is a parallel connection.

The same thing applies to R3 and R4, and then the R1||R2 combination is in series with the R3||R4 combination.

Redrawing the resulting schematic should make it a bit clearer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPW5ZT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still a bit confused as to why R1 and R2 are not in series. It seems like they're in both series and parallel. If a current were to pass through R1 wouldn't it also end up only passing through R2? I think my understanding of series connections is missing something but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 2):

If you redraw the circuit a bit differently, you will easily see how resistors combine together as shown below:

[image]